# How to make QWidget behave like QMessageBox?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qmessagebox

I've been trying to create a `QWidget` which behave like `QMessageBox`.
When I have for example two `QWidget` and one `QMessageBox` until I don't close the `QMessageBox` I can't available `QWidget`!
Is it exist the function that the `QWidget` behave like this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand you right, but I think you have to call

```
yourWidget->setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal)
```

(before showing your Widget) to get the Messagebox-like behaviour...